# pagination.js not working in webpack rails

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to install `pagination.js` and `jquery-ui` in rails 6 using webpack. But it's not working. I using CDN then working

Added pagination.js and jquery-ui package using npm

`npm i paginationjs`

`npm i jquery-ui`

```
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("jquery");
global.$ = global.jQuery = jQuery;
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;

require("jquery-ui");
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
require("select2");
require("lodash");
require("@nathanvda/cocoon");
require("paginationjs");
```

Getting error ***Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pagination is not a function*** and ***$(...).autocomplete is not a function***

Comment: What is the jquery version you use with the CDN.?

Comment: are all the latest versions.